# sbteclipse: create build.sbt and plugins.sbt

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin, sbteclipse

I have downloaded sbt and to resolve the proxy maven repository errors, I have created repositories files with my-maven-proxy-releases:  under ~/.sbt

When I do a sbt about, I get the below details:

```
"~\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.4"\jars\sbt.jar"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: C:\
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/C:/)
[info] This is sbt 1.0.4
[info] The current project is {file:/C:/}root 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.12.4
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, sbt.plugins.Giter8TemplatePlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.12.4
```

Now, I wanted to import a project in eclipse and I googled. This is the details I found.

```
1. ~/.sbt/<sbt-version>/plugins/plugins.sbt
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
  sbteclipse 

2. ~/.sbt/<sbt-version>/plugins/build.sbt
   for scala versions and dependencies.
```

But I am confused on where to create the build.sbt and plugins.sbt as my folder structure is like this:

```
~/.sbt/1.0
~/.sbt/1.3
```

and I do not see ~/.sbt/1.0.4 which is displayed in sbt about.

Please guide if my understanding wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand sbt [project structure](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Directories.html) and the difference between project-local and [global plugins](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Using-Plugins.html#Global+plugins).

As you would usually use eclipse plugin globally you should put it in

```
~/.sbt/<sbt-version>/plugins/plugins.sbt
```

(as you wrote correctly), where `<sbt-version>` is

- `0.13` for any sbt `0.13.*`
- `1.0` for any sbt `1.*.*` (this may seem [unintuitive](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3858), but it's okay)

I guess, `~/.sbt/1.3` is just a typo and is meant to be `~/.sbt/0.13`.

Also you normally don't put anything in `~/.sbt/<sbt-version>/plugins/build.sbt`. If you need to have some global settings (including those for the global plugins), you should put them in

```
~/.sbt/<sbt-version>/global.sbt
```

Read about global settings [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Global-Settings.html).

---

With non-global plugins and settings it's all the same minus the `~/.sbt/<sbt-version>/` part:

- use `<your-project>/plugins/plugins.sbt` for plugins
- and `<your-project>/build.sbt` for project settings